# Add Camera Solver constraint to a camera that's set up for a frame other than 1?

Tags: camera, tracking, fspy

When I add a *Camera Solver* constraint (created from tracking a video clip) to a camera (in my case one imported from fSpy), Blender always behaves as if the camera is set up as it should be for frame 1 of the clip.

Is there any way to tell Blender that the camera is oriented as it should be for some frame other than 1, e.g. frame 148?

After solving a nodal pan, I find it easier to determine the camera's position using fSpy. This works perfectly if I always work with frame 1. However frame 1 isn't always the most convenient frame (e.g. everything can be lined up much more nicely at some point in the middle of the pan).

E.g. here I scrubbed to frame 148, exported out this frame, imported it into fSpy and then imported the resulting fSpy project back into Blender. I'm about to add the *Camera Solver* constraint to the resulting fSpy camera:

[image: camera solver]

However, when I add the *Camera Solver* constraint, I end up with this:

[image]

Blender always behaves as if the camera was setup for frame 1 (and places the markers accordingly), *then* it advances forward from there to the currently selected frame (148 in this case) so the origin ends up off to the right (this was a panning shot) rather than everything staying as it was.

So is there some way to tell Blender that the camera is currently oriented as it should be for frame 148 and adjust everything relative to that, when adding the *Camera Solver* constraint, rather than always assuming the camera is set up for frame 1?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (i could be wrong) because Fspy is for still images only

Comment: A clip is a sequence of still images. The process I describe works perfectly for establishing the initial position of your camera, for a nodal track, if you always work with frame 1 in fSpy. But sometimes frame 1 isn't the most convenient frame to work with. So I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to tell Blender that instead of frame 1, the camera is positioned as it should be for e.g. frame 148 and adjust everything relative to that.